# simple_form associations and mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, simple-form

I get this message when I try to add an association in my form:

```
Association :role not found
```

role.rb

```
...
many :users

key :name, String
key :description, String
...
```

user.rb

```
...
belongs_to :role

key :username, String
key :password, String
key :password_salt, String
key :email, String
key :first_name, String
key :last_name, String
key :active, Boolean, :default => true
...
```

form

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.association :role %>
  <%= f.input :active, :as => :boolean %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Has anyone used associations in [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with mongomapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, simple_form only works with active_record. But if you want to use it with any active_model compatible library, make sure that you have passed the collection to association helper. eg.:

`<%= f.association :role, :collection => Role.all %>`

But I think that mongomapper is not an active_model compatible library.

Comment: MongoMapper 0.9 uses ActiveModel, but I believe associations are an ActiveRecord thing still and not standardized by ActiveModel.